# DiscordJS, MongoDB find string in object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I need some help. I am currently working on a task system in my discordbot. I like to mention: I am working with MongoDB for like 6-7 days. So I am a newcomer with databases.

What I already tried:

1. Create a command do give someone a new task: "/auftrag @User "
2. Saving data to mongodb database.
3. Create a command to see my current tasks: "/aufgaben"

Everything works fine. But I have problems with the /aufgaben command. It says that "taskId" is not defined. How am I able to get the taskId from the database?

auftrag.js: https://sourceb.in/2SScUsBXDs

aufgaben.js: https://sourceb.in/9GlG9foxcH

aufgaben-schema.js: https://sourceb.in/A7g2i38Qq6

database-file: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811138759114227724/816249915889680384/unknown.png

Comment: Well, there is `const guildId = message.guild.id` and `const userId = message.author.id` but you never define `taskId`.

Comment: Thats right! But how am I able to define it from the database?